# Check if transformations are linear or not

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have the following transformations:

$$\varphi\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2+1,x_3+2)$$
$$\varphi\mathbf{x}=(2x_1+x_2,x_1+x_3,x^2_3)$$

As far as I know, I have to check if the transformations satisfy the following criteria:

$$
\mathbf{A}(a+b)=\mathbf{A}a+\mathbf{A}b\tag{1}$$
$$\mathbf{A}(\lambda{a})=\lambda\mathbf{A}a\tag{2}$$

The main problem is that I am confused what should I take as $a$ and what as $b$ and how to apply $\mathbf{A}$ to them (just not sure how it should look like).

Comment: Does it look linear to you?  As a good first check, it is easy to see that any linear transformation takes $\vec 0$ to $\vec 0$.

Comment: You take them to be arbitrary vectors.  For example, let $\mathbf a = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $\mathbf b=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$.

Comment: In your criteria, $A$ is the transformation $\varphi$, and $a$ and $b$ will be two vectors (represented by $\textbf{x}$ in your top equations).

Comment: @lulu, no it does not look linear, but I have to prove that, nobody caries what I feel

Comment: Did you try my hint?  It works for one of the two, not the other.

Comment: I should add:  as a general rule, it is always a good idea to "decide" what the answer is before you actually prove it, on the grounds that it is easier to prove or disprove a precise statement than it is to investigate an uncertain matter.  If you believe that neither example is linear, then you can try to find a concrete failure of linearity. If you fail to find an example of such you can revise your belief.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** I've answered enough of these "how do I show that a function is linear?" questions over the years that I've decided to make an authoritative post that I can link to in the future.  So that's why there's way more here than asked for by OP.  Let me know if you think I've left out something important.  And enjoy.

#### Table of Contents

- **What Is a Linear Map?**
- **Examples of Linear Maps**
- **Showing a Map Is Linear**
- **Appendix: Alternate Names for Linear Maps**

---

#### What Is a Linear Map?

A linear map $T:V\to W$ is a function between the two $\Bbb F$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$ that "preserve" the fundamental operations on a vector space.  In words, $T$ is a linear map iff it takes a scalar multiple to a scalar multiple and a sum to a sum.  More precisely, for all $\mathbf u,\mathbf v\in V$ and for all $k\in\Bbb F$, $$\begin{array}{cr}T(\mathbf u+\mathbf v) = T(\mathbf u)+T(\mathbf v) &\text{(Additivity)} \\ T(k\mathbf v) = kT(\mathbf v) &\text{(Homogeneity)}\end{array}$$

Notice that on the left hand sides of the equations, the operations are occuring in $V$ whereas on the right hand sides, the operations are occuring in $W$.

However, we can also see linear combinations as the fundamental operation on a vector space.  In that case we may want to instead define a linear map as a function which "preserves" (binary) linear combinations.  Specifically, for all $\mathbf u,\mathbf v\in V$ and for all $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb F$, $$T(\alpha\mathbf u+\beta\mathbf v) = \alpha T(\mathbf u)+\beta T(\mathbf v)$$

As before, notice that the linear combination on the LHS of the equation occurs in $V$ whereas on the RHS it occurs in $W$.

**Exercise 1:** Prove that the following statements are equivalent: Let $T:V\to W$ where $V$ and $W$ are $\Bbb F$-vector spaces.  For all $\mathbf u,\mathbf v,\mathbf v_1,\mathbf v_2,\dots, \mathbf v_k\in V$ and for all $\alpha, \beta, \beta_1,\beta_2,\dots, \beta_k\in\Bbb F$,

1. $T(\mathbf u+\mathbf v) = T(\mathbf u) + T(\mathbf v)$ and $T(\alpha\mathbf v) = \alpha T(\mathbf v)$.
2. $T(\alpha\mathbf u+\beta\mathbf v) = \alpha T(\mathbf u)+\beta T(\mathbf v)$.
3. $T(\mathbf u+\alpha\mathbf v) = T(\mathbf u)+\alpha T(\mathbf v)$.
4. $T\left(\sum_{i=1}^k \beta_i\mathbf v_i\right) = \sum_{i=1}^k \beta_iT(\mathbf v_i)$.

Hence any of these four conditions can be used to check whether a given map is linear.  In practice, they are all equally easy but the third usually requires slightly less writing.

**Exercise 2:** Let $\mathbf 0_V$ denote the zero vector in $V$ and $\mathbf 0_W$ the zero vector in $W$.  Prove that if $T$ is a linear map, then $T(\mathbf 0_V) = \mathbf 0_W$.

Note that the [contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) of the above is often used as a way to show that a map is *not* linear.  That is, if $T(\mathbf 0_V)\ne \mathbf 0_W$, then $T$ is not linear.  Because it is usually very easy to evaluate $T$ at the zero vector, this is often a useful way to very quickly show a map is non-linear.

---

#### Examples of Linear Maps

You can confirm that the following constitute linear maps on appropriately chosen domains:

- The function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by $f(x)=ax$ for some real number $a$.
- The function $T:P_n \to P_{n+1}$ given by $(Tp)(x)=xp(x)$ where $P_n$ is the vector space of all polynomials of degree $\le n$.
- The derivative at a point: $\left.\dfrac{d}{dx}\right|_p$.  This is a linear map on the vector space of differentiable functions (yes, there are vector spaces where the vectors are functions).
- The integral over $[a,b]$: $\int_a^b$.  This is a linear map on the vector space of continuous (or Lebesgue integrable) functions.

**Warning: An Important Non-Example**
There is one type of map which is sometimes called a "linear function" which is in fact not linear with respect to the definition used in this answer: a line *not containing the origin*.  Such a line is a function of the type $$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R \\ f(x) = ax+b$$ where $b\ne 0$.  In analytic geometry and calculus we would call this a linear function because geometrically its *graph is a line in the $xy$-plane*.  However in linear algebra, this is **NOT** a linear map.

---

#### Showing a Map Is Linear

Now it's time to look at some examples of how to use the definition of a linear map to ascertain whether a given map is linear or not.  But, looking at the definition, we might wonder "How can we check whether a property of a map holds for *every single* $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf v$, etc?"  Well, obvious we aren't going to check every one of the (usually) infinite number of possible choices individually.  Instead we show that if you take *arbitrary* vectors and scalars, that the additivity and homogeneity properties hold.  Let's look at some examples.

**First Example: Using the Definition**
Let $T$ be defined by $$T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2 \\ T(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (3x_1-x_2, 2x_1)$$

Test of Additivity: Let $\mathbf u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $\mathbf v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ be two arbitrary vectors in $\Bbb R^3$.  Then, we see from the definition of $T$ that

$$\begin{align}
T(\mathbf u+\mathbf v) &= T\big((u_1,u_2,u_3)+(v_1,v_2,v_3)\big) \\
&= T(u_1+v_1,u_2+v_2,u_3+v_3) \\
&= (3(u_1+v_1)-(u_2+v_2), 2(u_1+v_1)) \\
&= (3u_1+3v_1-u_2-v_2,2u_1+2v_1) \\
&= (3u_1-u_2,2u_1)+(3v_1-v_2,2v_1) \\
&= T(u_1,u_2,u_3) + T(v_1,v_2,v_3) \\
&= T(\mathbf u) + T(\mathbf v)
\end{align}$$

Because $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ were arbitrary vectors in $\Bbb R^3$, this shows that $T$ is additive for all $\mathbf u, \mathbf v\in \Bbb R^3$.

Test of Homogeneity: Let $\mathbf u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ be an arbitrary vector in $\Bbb R^3$ and $k$ be an arbitrary real number.  Then, we see from the definition of $T$ that

$$\begin{align}
T(k\mathbf u) &= T\big(k(u_1,u_2,u_3)\big) \\
&= T(ku_1,ku_2,ku_3) \\
&= (3(ku_1)-(ku_2), 2(ku_1)) \\
&= (k(3u_1-u_2),k(2u_1)) \\
&= k(3u_1-u_2,2u_1) \\
&= kT(u_1,u_2,u_3) \\
&= kT(\mathbf u)
\end{align}$$

Because $\mathbf u$ was an arbitrary vector in $\Bbb R^3$ and $k$ was an arbitrary real number, this shows that $T$ is additive for all $\mathbf u\in \Bbb R^3$ and $k\in\Bbb R$.

Conclusion: Because $T$ is both additive and homogeneous, we conclude that $T$ is linear.$\ \ \ \ \square$

But, it's a little bit of a pain to have to check two different properties of a map separately.  Especially when Looking at exercise 1, we see it's not necessary.  Let's see an example of how to test the additivity and homogeneity properties at the same time.

**Second Example: Using Condition 3 from Exercise 1**
Let $\Gamma$ be defined by $$\Gamma:P_3\to \Bbb R \\ \Gamma(p) = p(1)$$
where $P_3$ is the set of all polynomials with real coefficients and degree $\le 3$.

So first, we does an arbitrary element of $P_3$ look like?  Well it's a polynomial of degree at most $3$.  So it should look like $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ where any of the coefficients could potentially be $0$.  We see that the map $\Gamma$ is the function which "eats" $p$ and spits out the number you get when you evaluate $p$ at $1$.  We now show that this is linear.

Let $p$ and $q$ be two arbitrary elements of $P_3$ (so $p$ and $q$ are two polynomials of degree at most $3$) and let $\alpha$ be an arbitrary real number.  Then we see that

$$\begin{align*}
\Gamma(p+\alpha q) &= (p+\alpha q)(1) \\
&= p(1) + (\alpha q)(1) \\
&= p(1) + \alpha q(1) \\
&= \Gamma(p) + \alpha \Gamma(q)
\end{align*}$$

Hence, by the result of exercise 1, we see that $T$ is linear.$\ \ \ \ \square$

Notice that this was a bit shorter (though not necessarily any easier) than using the definition of linearity directly.

Now I'd be remiss if I didn't show an example of a function that's *not* linear.  Here is a function that doesn't look too different from the first example.

**Third (Non-)Example: Take 1**
Let $S$ be defined by $$S:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2 \\ S(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (3x_1-x_2, |x_1|)$$

I claim that this is non-linear.  To show this, let's try to prove that it is linear and see what (if anything) goes wrong.  Again, we'll use condition 3 from exercise 1 because -- as I've mentioned -- it tends to produce the shortest proofs.

Let $\mathbf u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $\mathbf v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ be two arbitrary vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ and let $k$ be an arbitrary real number.  Then, we see from the definition of $S$ that

$$\begin{align}
S(\mathbf u+k\mathbf v) &= S\big((u_1,u_2,u_3)+k(v_1,v_2,v_3)\big) \\
&= S(u_1+kv_1,u_2+kv_2,u_3+kv_3) \\
&= (3(u_1+kv_1)-(u_2+kv_2), |u_1+kv_1|)
\end{align}$$

and that

$$\begin{align}
S(\mathbf u)+kS(\mathbf v) &= S(u_1,u_2,u_3)+kS(v_1,v_2,v_3) \\
&= (3u_1-u_2, |u_1|)+k(3v_1-v_2, |v_1|) \\
&= (3u_1-u_2, |u_1|)+(3kv_1-kv_2, k|v_1|) \\
&= (3(u_1+kv_1)-(u_2+kv_2), |u_1|+k|v_1|)
\end{align}$$

However, we know that it is not generally true that $|u_1+kv_1| = |u_1|+k|v_1|$ (take $u_1=-1$, $k=1=v_1$ for an example).  Hence it's not true that $S(\mathbf u+k\mathbf v)= S(\mathbf u)+kS(\mathbf v)$ for all $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf v$, and $k$.  Thus $S$ is not linear.$\ \ \ \ \square$

Do we really need to go through all of this work to show that $S$ is non-linear, though?  The answer is no.

**Third (Non-)Example: Take 2**
Consider the same $S$ as defined above.  Notice that if $\mathbf v = (1,2,3)$ and $k=-1$, then $$\begin{align*}S((-1)\mathbf v) &= S(-1,-2,-3) \\ &= (3(-1)-(-2), |(-1)|) \\ &= (-1,1) \\ &\color{red}{\ne} -1(1,1) \\ &= -1(3(1)-(2),|(1)|) \\ &= -1S(1,2,3) \\ &= -1S(\mathbf v)\end{align*}$$

Hence $S$ is not homogeneous, and thus it is not linear.$\ \ \ \ \square$

So you see, when proving that a map is not linear, it suffices to show that one of th defining properties fails for any specific vectors/ scalars that you choose.  If a map is not homogeneous (or additive) for even one pair $\mathbf v$ and $k$ (or $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$), then by definition it's not linear.  The trick is to find a suitable pair.

**Exercise 3:** Exercise 2 gave us a condition that will sometimes show us a map is not linear.  Could we have used it here to show that $S$ is not linear?  If so, use it to prove this a third time.  If not, why?

Now that we've seen how to show a map is linear or not, we can prove a statement we made in the last section.

**Exercise 4:** Let $a,b\in \Bbb R$ and define $$f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R \\ f(x) = ax+b$$  Prove that $f$ is a linear map if and only if $b=0$.

**Exercise 5:** Show that every linear map from $\Bbb R^m$ to $\Bbb R^n$ has the form $$T(x_1,x_2, \dots, x_m) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^m a_{1i}x_i,\ \sum_{i=1}^m a_{2i}x_i,\ \cdots\ ,\ \sum_{i=1}^m a_{ni}x_i\right)\tag{1}$$ for some constants $a_{ij}\in \Bbb R$.  Does the converse hold?  That is, will every map $T:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^n$ of the form (1) be linear?

---

#### Appendix: Alternate Names for Linear Maps

Linear maps go by several other names as well.  Here are some:

- linear mapping
- linear transformation
- linear homomorphism
- vector homomorphism
- linear function (sometimes)
- morphism of $\mathsf{K}$-$\mathsf{Vect}$

Answer (score 2):

In your case you have to check if, for any $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3),\mathbf{y} = (y_1,y_2,y_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and for any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$ \varphi (\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{y}) = \varphi\mathbf{x}+\varphi\mathbf{y} $$
and 
$$ \varphi(\lambda \mathbf{x}) = \lambda \varphi \mathbf{x}. $$

Answer (score 0):

The definition is wrong.

If $A$ is a linear transformation, so:

- $A(v+u) = A(v) + A(u)$
- $A(av) = aA(v)$

Where $u,v$ are vectors and $a$ is a scalar.

So, if $x=(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3})$ is a vector and $a$ a scalar,  then

$\phi(ax) = \phi(ax_{1},ax_{2},ax_{3}) =  (ax_{1},ax_{2} + 1,ax_{3} + 2).$

Then you have $\phi(ax) = a\phi(x)?$

Think about it!

Answer (score 0):

Check:
$$
 \varphi \left( \alpha x + y \right) \stackrel{?}{=} \alpha \varphi \left( x \right) + \varphi \left( y \right)
$$

The second part is the that one that fails and illustrates the application.

---

Given $$\varphi \left( x \right) = 
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  2x_{1} + x_{2} \\
   x_{1} + x_{3} \\
   x_{3}^{3}
\end{array} \right]$$
check that
$$
\varphi \left( \alpha x + y \right) = 
\alpha \varphi \left( x \right) + \varphi \left( y \right) 
$$

Using the definition of the function,
$$
\varphi \left( \alpha x + y \right)
=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  2\alpha x_{1} + \alpha x_{2} + y_{1} + y_{2} \\
   \alpha x_{1} + \alpha x_{3} + y_{2} + y_{3} \\
   \color{red}{\left( \alpha x_{3} + y_{3} \right)^{3}}
\end{array} \right]
=
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  \alpha \left( 2 x_{1} +  x_{2} \right) + y_{1} + y_{2}\\
   \alpha \left( x_{1} + x_{3} \right) + y_{2} + y_{3} \\
   \color{red}{\alpha^{3} x_{3}^{3} + 
3 \alpha^{2} x_{3}^{3} y_{3}  + 
3 \alpha x_{3} y_{3}^{2} + 
y_{3}^{3}}
\end{array} \right]$$